# MVC jQuery AJAX Post requiring Authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a pretty standard ajax post call from a Forms Authenication mvc site.
This ajax call I can do when I'm on a computer inside out domain but when I try this from a computer not on our domain the Post call asks for my username/password.

It should be noted that to get to this page in the first place I needed to login in the first place.

Can anyone help?

Ajax call code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{url}}",
    data: "{{data}}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) { OnSuccess(msg, Id); },
    error: function(msg) { OnFail(msg, Id); }
});
```

The `{{url}}` is in the format `/areaname/controllername/actionname`.

The `{{data}}` is in the format `{ key: value, key2: value }`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the request. It would be your intranet settings

Comment: karthikr: could you please explain more?

Comment: may be you have some firewall or some authentication settings which is throwing the authentication. You can check with your company's network administrator. They can tell you more about "Site authentication" or basic authentication that they might have put in place

Comment: Kathikr: the web.config defines the Authentication mode as "Forms". Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: No. Iwas not talking about your code/application. I was talking about general access to internal URLs within your firm from outside the LAN

Comment: Kathikr: From the external computer I can browse the site and get to this page. So i think the access to the site is OK. But when I click a link that performs the Ajax Post I then get the Authentication Exception "You do not have permission to view this Directory of Page."

Comment: Ok.. does this url `/areaname/controllername/actionname` have any authentication required decorators ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE 10 the default "Do Not Track" is set and therefore Cookies are not being used when the Ajax post is being used.

I simply set added the cookieless="UseCookies" attribute to the Authentication type, and it worked.